Riemannian manifold with non-compact closed ball.
Let $(M,g)$ be a riemannian manifold, and $d_g$ the induced distance function. I am trying to pin-point a necessary and sufficient condition for $M$ to admit at least one closed metric-ball which is not compact. Of course, Hopf-Rinow implies that necessary conditions are

$(M,g)$ is geodesically not-complete.
$M$ is non-compact

An example of such space would be $M=\mathbb{R}^{n}/\{(0,0)\}$ with the euclidean metric, a closed non-compact ball in $M$ being say an $n$-disk centered at $(1,0)$ of radius $2$.
An other example would be an open ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the euclidean metric, say $M=B(0,1)$, a non-compact closed ball in $M$ being a closed ball of radius $2$ centered at $0$ (wich covers all of $B(0,1)$). More generally, any non-compact manifold with finite diameter will have a closed non-compact metric-ball constructed in an anlogous way.
It almost seems like $(M,g)$ geodesically not complete would be a sufficient condition to conclude existence of a closed non-compact ball, but It's not obvious to me how such a ball could constructed.
Related : Example of a connected Riemannian manifold containing a non-compact closed bounded set
Thank you, L.

HRT gives you both necessary and sufficient conditions. Do you know that compact metric spaces are complete?

Your first example doesn't work, because the origin is not a point in the space.

@MoisheKohan Thank you. If you know a reference where this is proved, I will be happy to accept this as an answer. (Yes, I'm aware that compact metric spaces are complete.)

@JackLee Thank you, I think the example is fixed now.

This is really quite obvious: Suppose that every closed metric ball in $(M,g)$ is compact. Let $(x_i)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $M$; then this sequence is bounded, hence, is contained in some closed metric ball $\bar{B}(x,R)$. By compactness of this ball, the sequence $(x_i)$ converges. Hence, $(M,g)$ is complete. In other words, the Heine-Borel property implies completeness. (There is nothing special about Riemannian manifolds, it is a general property of metric spaces.) Now, state the contrapositive...
